# IIS Url Rewrite Full URL to New Domain

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-8.5

Im looking for a Url Rewrite rule for the following:

Id like to 301 redirect a domain to a new domain and keep the full url intact.

so for example:

- mydomain.co.uk/news   **>**   mydomain2.com/news
- mydomain.co.uk/about   **>**   mydomain2.com/about
- mydomain.co.uk/level1/level2   **>**   mydomain2.com/level1/level2

so on and so forth. Basically a swap like for like and just the domain to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will put in a rewrite rule like this in the site that hosts mydomain.co.uk

```
<rule name="Full URL to new domain">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain2.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Does not recognize http vs https